# Gensim sentences from ontology corpus Unicode error

Tags: python, unicode, gensim, word2vec

I'm on Windows OS10, using python 2.7.15 | Anaconda. Whenever I run

```
mymodel=gensim.models.Word2Vec.load (pretrain)
mymodel.min_count = mincount
sentences =gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence('ontology_corpus.lst')
mymodel.build_vocab(sentences, update=True) # ERROR HERE ****
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runWord2Vec.py", line 23, in <module>
    mymodel.build_vocab(sentences, update=True)
  File "C:xxxx\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ba
se_any2vec.py", line 936, in build_vocab
    sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, progress_per=progress_per, tri
m_rule=trim_rule)
  File "C:xxxx\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\wo
rd2vec.py", line 1591, in scan_vocab
    total_words, corpus_count = self._scan_vocab(sentences, progress_per, trim_r
ule)
  File "C:xxxxx\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\wo
rd2vec.py", line 1560, in _scan_vocab
    for sentence_no, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
  File "C:xxxx\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\wo
rd2vec.py", line 1442, in __iter__
    line = utils.to_unicode(line).split()
  File "C:xxxx\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py"
, line 359, in any2unicode
    return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)
  File "C:xxxxx\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16,
in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 124: invalid
 continuation byte
```

Now this traces back to this LineSentence Class

```
class LineSentence(object):

def __init__(self, source, max_sentence_length=MAX_WORDS_IN_BATCH, limit=None):

    self.source = source
    self.max_sentence_length = max_sentence_length
    self.limit = limit

def __iter__(self):
    """Iterate through the lines in the source."""
    try:
        # Assume it is a file-like object and try treating it as such
        # Things that don't have seek will trigger an exception
        self.source.seek(0)
        for line in itertools.islice(self.source, self.limit):
            line = utils.to_unicode(line).split()
            i = 0
            while i < len(line):
                yield line[i: i + self.max_sentence_length]
                i += self.max_sentence_length
    except AttributeError:
        # If it didn't work like a file, use it as a string filename
        with utils.smart_open(self.source) as fin:
            for line in itertools.islice(fin, self.limit):
                line = utils.to_unicode(line).split() # ERROR HERE *************
                i = 0
                while i < len(line):
                    yield line[i: i + self.max_sentence_length]
                    i += self.max_sentence_length
```

In the last return that can be seen from the error, I can just change the error parameter to be error='ignore' or change this line:

```
 utils.to_unicode(line).split()
```

to this:

```
 line.split()
```

ontology_corpus.lst file sample:

```
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0090141> EquivalentTo <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0065007> and  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002213> some <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0000266> 
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0090141> SubClassOf <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0065007>
```

The problem is that it's working but I'm afraid that the results will be flawed due to the encoding error ignored! Is there a solution to this or would my approach will be just fine?

Comment: Is this "ontology_corpus.lst" part of gensim, or is this something you provided?

Comment: I have generated that one, question updated with sample @lenz

Comment: In that case, you should create it again and make sure it's encoded with UTF-8. Or convert it using a tool like `iconv`.

Comment: What about using `line.encode("utf-8").split()` ? And would it be similar to just using 
 `line.split()` ?@lenz

Comment: Windows often use `cp1252` encoding (or another 8bit encoding if the language do not use west european latin charset). Unsure whether this can help...

Comment: `line.encode('utf8')` is more or less the opposite of `util.to_unicode(line)`. Trying combinations of `encode()` and `decode()` at random will eventually make the exception go away, but it might leave you with corrupt data.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because some line or lines in your file contain data that is not properly UTF8-encoded.

If the `build_vocab()` otherwise succeeds, it might not make that much difference in your final results, if the corruption is unintentional, rare, or does not affect the word-vectors you're specifically interested in. (Your example lines don't contain any UTF8 corruption, or characters likely to have encoding issues.)

But if it's a concern, you could try to identify the exact line with the problem, by reading the `sentences` yourself to trigger the error outside of `build_vocab()`. For example:

```
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    print(i)
```

Where it stops (if it's an error which ends iteration), or where the error message is interleaved with line-numbers, will give you a hint of the line(s) where there's an issue. You can examine those in a text-editor to see which characters are involved. You could then consider removing/changing those characters, or attempting to discover the file's true encoding & re-encode as UTF8, using that knowledge of the involved ranges/characters.

(A separate note about your apparent corpus: note that word-vector training is best if the many alternate examples of a single token are spread throughout the corpus, interleaved with contrasting examples of other tokens. So if your corpus is a dump from some other source that clumps all related tokens, like say `<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0090141>`, together, you may get somewhat improved final vectors if you shuffle the lines before training.)

Comment: Thank you for the insight about the training! I will try to track the error and see what happens